# asp classic lightbox and checking sessions

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, lightbox

ASP classic website with lightbox.  After logging in, I check certain sessions to allow users to access certain webpages.

Can I initiate/call the lightbox function using asp classic? If not, then is my only option to utilize a javascript cookie function?

Comment: Since ASP runs first, you could feed a TRUE/FALSE statement into  javascript to determine access.

Comment: Can javascript look at the asp sessions? Example code?

Comment: It can't "look" at it.  You have to inject the value.  For Example: var x=<%=true%>;